# Python Application Assistance

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, variables

The requirements of my project are as follows:

• Create a Python application that will loop between 1 and 100

• The numbers are to be printed out alongside their squared value

• The app should stop when a squared value of 200 or more is reached

• Reconfigure the application to take in a user value as desired.
For example, if you were to input the value 8 (DO NOT USE THIS VALUE), your
application would produce all squared values from 1 to 8.

This is what I have so far,

**`def sq_nos(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        j = i**2
        print(i, j)
        if j > 200:
            break
start = int(input("enter start: "))
end = int(input("enter end: "))
sq_nos(start, end)**`

This code is still printing the square value of 255, any solutions?

Any other feedback would be appreciated too.

Comment: If the square is greater than 200, you are printing it first, and breaking after that. If you don't want printing it, check/break before print

Comment: Check this for visualizing code execution https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to test before printing the square value. Thus:

```
def sq_nos(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        j = i**2
        if j> 200 :
            break
        else:
            print(i,j)
```

But to solve the assignment, I don't know why you are asking for the start value. You only have to ask for the limit of the squared value. Thus, the following would be correct:

```
def sq_nos(limit ):
    for i in range(1, 100):
        if i**2 > limit:
            return
        else:
            print(i,i**2)

limit = int(input("enter the limit of the squared value: "))
sq_nos(limit )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check and break before printing.
Try with this code.

```
def sq_nos(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        j = i**2
        if j > 200:
            break
        print(i, j)

#start = int(input("enter start: "))
#end = int(input("enter end: "))
sq_nos(1, 100)
```

and output is

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
10 100
11 121
12 144
13 169
14 196
```